# Smooth onscroll transition for header

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following javascript for a fixed header onscroll, but it jumps slightly after one scroll on certain pages, and it's the same CSS for every page. [This page](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/restaurants/italian-restaurants.html) is fine for some reason, but [other pages](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/shops-and-shopping.html) don't have a smooth transition and it jumps down:

```
<script>
$(document).scroll( function() {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( value > 48 ) {
        $(".header").css("position", "fixed");
        $("body").css("padding-top", "90px");
    } else {
        $(".header").css("position", "relative");
        $("body").css("padding-top", "0");
    }
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background: #E9ECEF url("/images/light_bg.jpg") repeat;
background: #EEE;
padding-top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
min-width: 250px;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1.7;
}

#top-nav-wrapper {
width: 100%;
background: #585864;
position: relative;
margin-top: 0px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #B8B8B8;
top: 0;
z-index: 2000;
background: #EEE;
margin-bottom: 3px;
}

body, .header {
background: #EEE;
}
.header {
position: relative;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
min-height: 90px;
z-index: 2000;
background: #E9ECEF url("/images/dark_bg.jpg") repeat;
border-bottom: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
border: 0;
background: #EEE;
height: 90px;
background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.95);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #C4C4C4;
}
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using chrome on a mac and it seems to work fine

Comment: I am using chrome on windows and I can see the slight jump. Maybe try and add a micro delay before adding the fixed attribute. I think that will fix it because the scroll event fires immediately when the user starts scrolling and thus the little jump before the page is actually scrolled.

Comment: Wrap your code inside the scroll in a function. We will call it: "setHeaderToFixed()". And replace the code inside the scroll event with: setTimeout(setHeaderToFixed, 10). I hope this makes sense. I am not sure that this will fix it; but it is a suggestion.